# What is the keyboard shortcut for cutting multiple files and pasting them at the same time?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I know Ctrl X does work with one file but I want to cut several video files in a specific order and paste them into a folder in the order that I cut the files.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask)! Just click the green checkmark under the answer you want to choose. [Here's an image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + click each file. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> to cut, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

Comment: Will this work if they are in different folders? If I "ctrl" one file then go into another folder etc. Then going ctrl x will cut them out of the different folders at once?

Comment: is it possible to use a keyboard button to "click each file" instead of the mouse? Looking for a keyboard only way.